# How to check if my html will print longer than one page?

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if there was a way using php or javascript to see if my webpage will be longer than one page when printed. I have specific elements that need to be at the bottom of the page regardless of how long the content in the middle of the page is, (max one page including footer).

Tried various css elements such as bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making a separate 'print.css' file that only alters the way a page looks when it is going to be printed? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">`. This can also be done with an `@media print { }` tag in your regular css file.

Comment: That's not what he asked. He wants to know how to determine the length of the html content before printing. If it's longer than 1 page, he can break the page to continue to the next page in a clean way.

Comment: I'm not bashing you, it's part of SO to keep content quality high, even after 3 years. I accidentally came across this questions as I was looking an answer for myself. It's not like I'm looking for bad posts or answers to downvote, it just happens I came across your post and took action as a member. I hope you understand.